# Sending data through ZeroMQ (zmqpp) using MsgPack gives 'msgpack::v1::insufficient_bytes' error

Tags: c++, c++11, zeromq, msgpack, messagepack

I made a PUB/SUB connection using [zmqpp](https://github.com/zeromq/zmqpp) and now I want to send data from the publisher to the subscribers using the header-only, C++11 version of [msgpack-c](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c).

The publisher has to send 2 `int64_t` numbers -- `header_1` and `header_2` -- followed by a `std::vector<T>` -- `data` --, where `T` is determined by the `(header_1, header_2)` combination.

Sinse there aren't that many examples on how to combine msgpack and zmqpp,  the idea I came up with is to send a 3-part message by using [`zmqpp::message::add/add_raw`](https://zeromq.github.io/zmqpp/classzmqpp_1_1message.html). Each part would be [packed](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v1_1_cpp_packer)/[unpacked](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/wiki/v1_1_cpp_unpacker) using msgpack.

The publisher packs a single data part as follows:

```
zmqpp::message msg;
int64_t header_1 = 1234567;
msgpack::sbuffer buffer;
msgpack::pack(buffer, header_1);
msg.add(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

And the receiver unpacks it like this:

```
zmqpp::message msg;
subscriberSock.receive(msg);

int64_t header_1;
msgpack::unpacked unpackedData;
// crash !
msgpack::unpack(unpackedData,
                static_cast<const char*>(msg.raw_data(0)),
                msg.size(0));
unpackedData.get().convert(&header_1);
```

When I run the code, I get the following error on the subscriber side:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'msgpack::v1::insufficient_bytes'
  what():  insufficient bytes
Aborted
```

Also, it seems that zmqpp has generated a 5-part message, even though I called `add()` only 3 times.

**Q1: Am I packing/unpacking the data correctly ?**

**Q2: Is this the proper method for sending msgpack buffers using zmqpp ?**

Here are the important parts of the code:

**Publisher**

```
zmqpp::socket publisherSock;
/* connection setup stuff ...*/

// forever send data to the subscribers
while(true)
{
    zmqpp::message msg;

    // meta info about the data
    int64_t header_1 = 1234567;
    int64_t header_2 = 89;
    // sample data
    std::vector<double> data;
    data.push_back(1.2);
    data.push_back(3.4);
    data.push_back(5.6);


    {
        msgpack::sbuffer buffer;
        msgpack::pack(buffer, header_1);
        msg.add(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        cout << "header_1:" << header_1 << endl;  // header_1:1234567
    }

    {
        msgpack::sbuffer buffer;
        msgpack::pack(buffer, header_2);
        msg.add(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        cout << "header_2:" << header_2 << endl;  // header_2:89
    }

    {
        msgpack::sbuffer buffer;
        msgpack::pack(buffer, data);
        msg.add_raw(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        std::cout << "data: " << data << std::endl;  // data:[1.2 3.4 5.6]
    }

    std::cout << msg.parts() << " parts" << std::endl;  // prints "5 parts"... why ?
    publisherSock.send(msg);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

**Subscriber**

```
zmqpp::socket subscriberSock;
/* connection setup stuff ...*/

zmqpp::message msg;
subscriberSock.receive(msg);

int64_t header_1;
int64_t header_2;
std::vector<double> data;

std::cout << msg.parts() << " parts" << std::endl;  // prints "5 parts"
{
    // header 1
    {
        msgpack::unpacked unpackedData;
        // crash !
        msgpack::unpack(unpackedData,
                        static_cast<const char*>(msg.raw_data(0)),
                        msg.size(0));
        unpackedData.get().convert(&header_1);
        cout << "header_1:" << header_1 << endl;
    }
    // header 2
    {
        msgpack::unpacked unpackedData;
        msgpack::unpack(unpackedData,
                        static_cast<const char*>(msg.raw_data(1)),
                        msg.size(1));
        unpackedData.get().convert(&header_2);
        cout << "header_2:" << header_2 << endl;
    }
    // data
    {
        msgpack::unpacked unpacked_data;
        msgpack::unpack(unpacked_data,
                        static_cast<const char*>(msg.raw_data(2)),
                        msg.size(2));
        unpacked_data.get().convert(&data);
        std::cout << "data:" << data << std::endl;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** Problem solved: As pointed out by @Jens, the correct way of packing/sending data is by using [`zmqpp::message::add_raw()`](https://zeromq.github.io/zmqpp/classzmqpp_1_1message.html#a9844b1ebf493a12e62788e94a64876e0)

```
zmqpp::message msg;
int64_t header_1 = 1234567;
msgpack::sbuffer buffer;
msgpack::pack(buffer, header_1);
msg.add_raw(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the calls to `msg.add(buffer.data(), buffer.size()`do not add a array of `buffer.size()` bytes, but call `message::add(Type const& part, Args &&...args)`, which

1. `msg << buffer.data()`, which probably calls `message::operator<<(bool)` since a pointer converts to bool
2. `add(buffer.size())` which then calls `msg << buffer.size()`, which adds a `size_t` value as the next part.

Looking at the zmqpp::message class, using message::add_raw should do the trick.

PS: This is all without any guarantee because I have never used zmqpp or msgpack.

Comment: Thanks, but even with `message::add_raw()` I still have the same crash on the subscriber. Also, instead of 6, zmqpp now generates 5 parts... and I don't understand why...

Comment: @865719 You have to replace all calls to message::add with message::add_raw. Instead of adding the int64 for both header fields, the pointer buffer.data() and buffer.size() are added. Could you add a `cout << msg.parts() << endl` after the other couts?

Comment: Yes! Now zmqpp creates a 3-part message as expected. Also, in the first example, I've mistakenly used index `3` instead of `2` when unpacking the the vector in the received side.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that using `add_raw` is the correct thing to do here.